# C# subscribe to event from another Task.Factory

Tags: c#, events

could please help with that. I can not subscribe for event fired by an object from another Task.
Note: If i took the code outside the Task, it works fine. you can see the commented code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _machines.Add(new Machine() { Ip = "192.168.1.10", Name = "Machine_01", Status = "Connected" });
        dgvMachines.DataSource = _machines;
    }

    private void startLiveMonitoringToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (_machines.Count <= 0) return;
        //_fpMachine = new ZktFingerPrint(_machines[0].Ip, _machines[0].Name);
        //_fpMachine.Connect();
        //_fpMachine.EnableLiveFingerPrintDetection();
        //_fpMachine.NewFingerPrintDetected += FpMachine_NewFingerPrintDetected;
        foreach (var machine in _machines)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                IFingerPrintMachine fpMachine = new ZktFingerPrint(machine.Ip, machine.Name);
                fpMachine.Connect();
                fpMachine.EnableLiveFingerPrintDetection();
                fpMachine.NewFingerPrintDetected += FpMachine_NewFingerPrintDetected;
            });
        }
    }

    private  void FpMachine_NewFingerPrintDetected(object sender, FingerPrintEventArgs e)
    {
        var fpr = new FingerPrintRecord(e.FingerPrintDateTime, e.UserId);
        dgvMonitor.Rows.Add("Machine_01", fpr.FingerPrintDateTime, fpr.UserSn);
    }
```

Comment: Is the event still running?  Add a dispose method in IFingerPrintMachine and then see if you get to the dispose method.

Comment: Your subscription is the last line in an anonymous method, just before fpMachine goes out of scope.

Comment: @bommelding No errors. just the FpMachine_NewFingerPrintDetected methoed does not fire

Comment: OK, who makes ZktFingerPrint, point to a driver library or manufacturer docs. We can't see what Connect() does for example. And tell us why this is inside a Start.Run()

Comment: Actually the library is already tested and works fine. If i take the  code outside the Task.Factory.StartNew it works as expected . The problem only with the Task

Comment: Then don't use that Task ??